# Use another variable value as variable value

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have variables in several projects that are substitutes the original `config` file value.
For instance, in project *X* the `config` key is `smtpServ`, and in project *Y* it's `smtp`.

I'd like to have 1 variable in a library set named `smtpServer` that should enter into `smtpServ` (project *X*) and `smtp` (project *Y*), so that I can keep it in 1 place.

Is this doable in the "Project Variables" view? (`/projects/service-name/variables`), or do I need to do it with a PS script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the library variable value in your project-specific variables.

For example, in project X, you can create a variable named `smtpServ` that has a value of `#{smtpServer}`. In project Y, you can create a variable named `smtp` that has a value of `#{smtpServer}`.

Then you can update the value of `smtpServer` once instead of N number of times.

I will add a note of caution here that with generic names like this, there is a chance for a collision between the names. Say that project Z already has a variable named `smtpServer`. In this case, you can't use the value `#{smtpServer}` because it would be an infinite loop. Likewise, if any other variable referenced `smtpServer`, it will use the project value and not the library set variable. The solution here could be to delete the `smtpServer` variable from the project.

I prefer to give my variable names a prefix if possible. I may name the library variable `global.smtpServer` and reference it as `#{global.smtpServer}` to make a collision less likely.